# Integration Services Project won't run unless Business Intelligence Development Studio is ran as administrator

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, bids

The error is "Unable to bulk copy data. You may need to run this package as an Administrator"

Same problem when I use the Execute Package Utility. I scheduled it as a job SSMS and it also fails, I assume because of the permissions issue.

The package grabs data and writes in to a database table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from "SQL Server Destination" to "OLEDB Destination"